# what is difference between store vs merge in ruby hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash, merge, store

i create a hash:

```
a = {}
=> {}
```

then:

```
a.store(:b, {})
=> {}
```

and:

```
a.merge!(c: {})
=> {:b=>{}, :c=>{}}
```

what are differences actually?

Comment: store accepts k and v, merge accepts another hash.

Comment: BTW, `a.store(:b, {})` is equivalent to `a[:b] = {}`

Answer (score 4):

[store](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-store) is an assignment method.

```
a = {}
# => {}
a.store(:b, {})
a
# => {:b=>{}}
# Here you are assigning a key :b with empty hash {}
```

Another example to make it clearer:

```
a = {}
# => {}
a.store("key", "value")
a
# => {"key"=>"value"}
```

[merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) on the other hand manipulates your existing hash by merging with a different hash.

Example:

```
a = {}
# => {}
a.merge({"key" => "value"})
# => {"key"=>"value"}
a 
# => {} # original value still unchanged 
a.merge!({"key" => "value"})
# => {"key"=>"value"} 
a
# => {"key"=>"value"} # original value updated
```

However unless you use `merge!` `a`'s value will not get changed i.e. merge will occur only for return.

Answer (score 2):

`store` takes just one key/value tuple as input and returns the stored value.

```
h1 = { foo: 'bar' }
h1.store(:baz, 1)          #=> 1
h1                         #=> { foo: 'bar', baz: 1 }
```

Whereas `merge!` accepts a hash as input and returns the updated hash:

```
h2 = { foo: 'bar' }
h2.merge!(baz: 1, buz: 2)  #=> { foo: 'bar', baz: 1, buz: 2 } 
h2                         #=> { foo: 'bar', baz: 1, buz: 2 }
```

Comment: Both examples look almost identical. Maybe you should merge a hash with more than one key-value pair.

Answer (score 2):

> what are differences actually?

I think the main difference is `merge!` will let you decide which value to keep when duplicate key is provided, since it expects a block as well.

On the other hand, when you use `store`, the previous value will be replaced by the latest value when duplicate key is provided.

`store`

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h1.store("b", 254)
                #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>254}
```

`merge!`

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
h1.merge!(h2) { |key, v1, v2| v1 }
                #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200, "c"=>300}
```

Answer (score 1):

`merge!` takes one argument, which is hash to merge into original. `store` takes two arguments, which is key and value to store. Therefore, with `merge!`, you can add multiple keys to original hash, like this:

```
a = {}
a.merge!(a: 'a', b: 'b')
a
# => {:a => "a", :b => "b"}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a hash `h`, [Hash#store](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-store) has the same effect as [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D): they both either add one key-value pair `k=>v` to `h` (if `h` does not have a key `k`) or modify the value of key `k` (if the hash already contains the key). Also, they both return `v`.

[Hash#merge!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) (aka `update`) has two forms. The first does the same thing as `store`, except it does it for each key-value pair in another hash. The second form uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Please refer to the docs for details on that form of the method. Both forms of `merge!` return the "merged" hash.

[Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) is not a relevant comparison as it does not mutate the hash.